# Finding XPCOM Contract IDs: components.Classes["THISPART"]

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

When you need to create or access well-known objects in XPCOM, where do you find their contract IDs?

Answer (score 2):

You also should look at the Mozilla code through http://mxr.mozilla.org to understand how people use interfaces and functions your want to use.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the object you are looking for.  Generally, the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En) will tell you what the contract ID is.  If there's a specific contract ID you are looking for, that'd be an easier to answer question.

Comment: Replace "generally" with "sometimes". However, I found all contract IDs I needed using Google. The documentation often does only describe the interface but does not contain the contract ID. Sometimes there isn't even a description of the interface on https://developer.mozilla.org/ even though the interface in question has appropriate comments on http://mxr.mozilla.org/. Sometimes even the documentation there is incomplete and you have to look at a certain implementation of the interface.

Comment: PS: How I use Google for this purpose: I just google for:
`getService(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceInQuestion)`
or
`createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceInQuestion)`

Comment: Note that it is a wiki and can be improved by you too.